# Почему иконка font awesome выходит за пределы button при уменшении размера кнопки?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Почему иконка font awesome выходит за пределы button при уменшении размера кнопки? и как убрать внешние отступы друг от друга?

Вот код:

```
<button><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></button>
<button><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></button>

.catalog__products-top button {
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите вкладку "Вычислено" (Computed)

border: 0;
line-height: 0;
box-sizing: content-box;

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: А как убрать внешние отступы у кнопок?

Comment: Скорее всего margin:0;

Answer (score 0):

Иконки fa зачастую имеют не точный размер, одна иконка может быть 13px в высоту и 12px в ширину.

Я пользуюсь глазомером